Why can i only use axios if scrapfly-sdk is installed?
Using Axios without scrapfly-sdk in dependencies
After deleting the folder "node_modules" putting "scrapfly-sdk": "0.5.1" in the dependencies and reinstalling axios again the error is gone and it compiles to js like normal. Why?
I wanted to use axios but i kept getting an error. I tried out a bit and then noticed a connection between this and "scrapfly-sdk"

What is the issue with using the sdk other than just prefering it not being there? A philospher once said "It is what it is".

it's just strange. I want to know why it doesn't automatically install it if it's needed for it to even run. And also, why ive never seen anyone talking about this when making a axios tutorial or something like that.

To get those answers you might need to do different Stack as this one is for fixing code, and it works if you do that.  It is strange its required but not packaged.
